# How do I get the latest/most recent item in the list with DateTime with a specific key?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm returning a flat `List` from my server with objects that contain a `createdAt`. I want to iterate through this list and find the most recent one created, sorted by a specific key, `kind`

for example, this is the data I'm receiving:

```dart
final list = [
  {id: '1a' kind: 'MOOD' createdAt: 2021-12-08 19:22:11.000Z},
  {id: '1b' kind: 'MOOD' createdAt: 2021-12-08 19:15:11.000Z},
  {id: '1c' kind: 'PRESSURE' createdAt: 2021-12-08 18:22:11.000Z},
  {id: '1d' kind: 'MOOD' createdAt: 2021-12-07 18:22:11.000Z},
  {id: '1e' kind: 'WEIGHT' createdAt: 2021-12-07 17:21:11.000Z},
]
```

I want to be able to get the most recent `createdAt`, *by* the item's `kind`, so, for example, I want to get `MOOD`'s most recent entry, it would be

```
{id: '1a' kind: 'MOOD' createdAt: 2021-12-08 19:22:11.000Z}
```

Similarly, I want to get `WEIGHT`'s most recent entry, which would return

```
  {id: '1e' kind: 'WEIGHT' createdAt: 2021-12-07 17:21:11.000Z},
```

I've tried using `firstWhere`, but I'm unsure how to find the most recent date of the list, so I'm a bit lost there. I also have access to [collection](https://pub.dev/packages/collection) if a method there is applicable.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use DateTime.parse to convert string to DateTime object. Then you can get milliseconds from epoch. For example:

```
  Map<String, dynamic> getElement(List list, String kind) {
  list.where((element) => element['kind'] == kind).toList().sort((a, b) {
    return DateTime.parse(b['createdAt']!).millisecondsSinceEpoch -
        DateTime.parse(a['createdAt']!).millisecondsSinceEpoch;
  });

  return list.first;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your objects match the next type:

```
class Obj {
  final String id;
  final String kind;
  final String createdAt;
  
  Obj(this.id, this.kind, this.createdAt);
  
  String toString() {
    return 'Obj{id: $id, kind: $kind, createdAt: $createdAt}';
  }
}
```

So you can use the next method to get the most recent one:

```
Obj findEarliestByKind(List<Obj> list, String kind) {
  final elems = list.where((Obj item) => item.kind == kind).toList();
  elems.sort((a, b) => DateTime.parse(b.createdAt).compareTo(DateTime.parse(a.createdAt)));
  return elems[0];
}
```

Some additional notes:

1. It's better to pass type as an Enum
2. It's needed to handle parsing and empty list exceptions